# ASP.NET MVC Razor Layouts - the url is not getting updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC so peace if I'm asking something stupid. The problem is, when I'm redirecting from the LogOn method it does not update the URL in the browser properly

```
 public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Menu");
        }
```

and although it renders the content from the Menu/Index view, the url remains

> http://localhost/App/account/logon#/WMSMobileWeb/account/logon

where it should have been,

> http://localhost/App/Menu/Index

I'm using Razor view engine with Layouts and with JQuryMobile. Any idea?

/Bumble Bee

Comment: I have exact same problem Bumble Bee, Did u solve using below suggestion? or got something using MVC/JQueryMobile. -- thanks

Comment: the below solution worked for me. It was basically the ajax requests that made the url problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, that you are calling this action using Ajax, that's why your URL doesn't change. 
[This question basically covers what you need to do redirects with Ajax approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: What was the solution that you implemented? I have the exact same issue. Thanks

Comment: @David It looks like redirection has to be done client side...  I'm going through the same thing... or turn of AJAX handling.